# Getting categories and all its products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model called ProductCategory(has many products) and a model Products(belongs to ProductCategory). I seed the product_categories table with this data here(I'm sure you've guessed it, it has only two cols (category and category_type).

```
product_categories = [
    {:category => "Arts", :category_type => "physical" },
    {:category => "Books", :category_type => "physical" },
    {:category => "Comics", :category_type => "digital" },
    {:category => "Diy & Craft", :category_type => "physical" },
    {:category => "E-books", :category_type => "digital" }
]
```

Now in my product index i want to display all the categories along with 10 random products in each of the categories. Later i will change that to the top ten. 
An example of what i'm ultimately hoping to achieve is [This http://s866.photobucket.com/user/tommyadey/media/products.jpg.html](http://s866.photobucket.com/user/tommyadey/media/products.jpg.html)
But in my case i want to display all the categories and see ten products from each categories.
I've tried:

```
ProductCategory.includes(:products).limit(10)
```

What would be the best way to go about this?
I'm not sure if this is meant to be advanced or simple, sorry if it's relatively easy, i'm still learning.
Thanks.

Comment: You mean 10 random products that belong to the product category right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProductCategories.includes(:products)

In your view:

```
<% @product_categories.each do |product_category| %>
  <%product_category.products.shuffle.take(10).each do |product| %>
    <-- display your product here -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vimsha, i'll go try that out.

Comment: it says column products.product_category_id does not exist but i have category_id in my products table.

Comment: When your declare your association, specify the foreign_key explicitly . `belongs_to :product_category, :foreign_key => "product_id"`

Comment: In the case where i have {:category => "Other", :category_type => "digital" } and {:category => "Other", :category_type => "physical" } Its only displaying the physical one. Can i make it display the two?